# SQL query label columns

Tags: sql, select, label, multiple-columns, impala

I would like to ask whether it is possible to label variables using SQL impala. Like giving an additional longer description apart from the title, in a SELECT query.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you simply want `select col1 as "longer description for column 1", col2 ...`?

Comment: I want to give to my table permanent labels for example: col1 title is date and i would like to also label it "Date that the purchase was made". That way, it will have a title and a label.

Comment: You may add a comment to the metastore with `comment on column <database>.<table>.<column> is "some description"`, but it is not exposed by default with a select statement.

Comment: Can you give sample expected output?

Comment: @jarlh Impala identifiers are case-insensitive and can contain only ASCII characters regardless of quoting

Comment: @astentx, do you mean regular identifier characters? (My example was all ASCII.)

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t a way to get a label in the column names , you could add a comment next to the column though like this :

Create database Employee (
Id int /* this is the identifier for employees/*
)